# Combine random strings from multiple txt files and echo

Tags: php

I want to combine random strings from three txt files, but I am not sure how to do it. My code doesn't work at all.

```
<?php

function jedan() {
    $f_contents = file("/ime/ime.txt"); 
    $line1 = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
} 

    function dva() {
    $f_contents = file("/prezime/prezime.txt"); 
    $line2 = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
    }

    function tri() {
    $f_contents = file("/email/email.txt"); 
    $line3 = $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
    }


    $result = "{$line1}{$line2}{$line3}";
    echo $result

?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Comment: You never call the functions. For example `$result = jedan();`

Comment: And... You never return anything from the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the functions and return something.

```
function jedan() {
    $f_contents = file("/ime/ime.txt"); 
    return $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
} 

function dva() {
    $f_contents = file("/prezime/prezime.txt"); 
    return $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
}

function tri() {
    $f_contents = file("/email/email.txt"); 
    return $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
}

$line1 = jedan();
$line2 = dva();
$line3 = tri();


$result = "{$line1}{$line2}{$line3}";
echo $result;
```

Or to make it less "[WET](https://www.codementor.io/joshuaaroke/dry-code-vs-wet-code-89xjwv11w)":

```
function RandomLine($url) {
    $f_contents = file($url); 
    return $f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];
} 

$line1 = RandomLine("/ime/ime.txt");
$line2 = RandomLine("/prezime/prezime.txt");
$line3 = RandomLine("/email/email.txt");


$result = "{$line1}{$line2}{$line3}";
echo $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use file_get_contents() which reads content from files.
In below scenario i have created three text files in my wamp64 folder, and reading its string and combining its output by appending.

```
 <?php

   $file1= file_get_contents('C:\wamp64\xyz.txt');
   $file2= file_get_contents('C:\wamp64\abc.txt');
   $file3= file_get_contents('C:\wamp64\pqr.txt');
   echo $file1.$file2.$file3;

 ?>
```

Comment: It needs to be a random string from each file.

Comment: The OP wants a random line from each file.